# Hardhat tests failing when testing require statement

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

Hi I am trying to test a smart contract I wrote using hardhat, with chai and @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers.

I have followed the documentation however I am having no luck.

Please see below the require statement I am trying to test

```
    function someFunc() external onlyOwner {
        require( _checkFunc(), "Some message");
        _then();
    }
```

The test that is failing is below

```
it('Some function fails due to not meeting required criteria', async () => {
        const testContract = await contract.deploy('test');
        await expect(testContract.someFunc()).to.be.revertedWith('Some message');
    });
```

Does anyone know what the issue is thanks, below is the error message?

```
Contract
  1) Some function fails due to not meeting required criteria


  0 passing (21s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract
       Some function fails due to not meeting required criteria:
     AssertionError: Expected an Error object
```

Comment: This looks like a configuration issue. Consider using my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template). It might just solve your problem.

Comment: please share full code and test file. for making it easy to understand what the problem is

Comment: Share the full code please for better understanding